# Python Dataframe to SQL Query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I have developed a Python script that reads a CSV file which is a result of a SQL query (just a `select * from table`) and I perform some transformations and calculations on that dataframe.

I get the dataframe using the following Python commands:

```
result=csv_df.sort_values(by=['column1','column2','column3'],ascending=True)
result=result.drop_duplicates(['column1','column2'])
```

Now I need to get the same table using a SQL Query. I have tried the following in T-SQL but I have not been succesful.

```
select * from data
    where column1 IN
    (select distinct column1,column2 from data)
 and 
    where column2 IN
    (select distinct column1,column2 from data)
    order by column1,column2;
```

I am new to SQL syntax, can someone help me with the query?

What I am trying to do is delete all the duplicated rows from the combination of `column1` and `column2`.

In Python the reason I include `column3` is because it has `NULL` values that I need to discard.

After this should I create a view to keep on performing calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a unique ID in table, consider taking the record with lowest ID of matching *column1* and *column2* pairs:

```sql
SELECT * FROM data AS main
WHERE main.ID IN
    (SELECT sub.MinID FROM
       (SELECT column1, column2, Min(ID) As MinID
        FROM data
        GROUP BY column1, column2) AS sub)
ORDER BY main.column1, main.column2;
```

Alternatively, with `JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT main.* FROM data AS main
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT column1, column2, Min(ID) As MinID
     FROM data
     GROUP BY column1, column2) AS sub
ON main.ID = sub.MinID
ORDER BY main.column1, main.column2;
```

Even still, with `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT main.* FROM data AS main
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM 
      (SELECT column1, column2, Min(ID) As MinID
       FROM data
       GROUP BY column1, column2) sub
   WHERE main.ID = sub.MinID)
ORDER BY main.column1, main.column2;
```

And a non-Window function query using correlated count subquery (for potential compatibility with MySQL, SQLite, and MS Access). This version leaves out records if any of two columns are `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT *, 
      (SELECT Count(*) FROM data sub
       WHERE sub.ID <= data.ID
       AND sub.column1 = data.column1
       AND sub.column2 = data.column2) AS rn
   FROM data) AS main
WHERE main.rn = 1
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Can you please elaborate on the logic behind the first answer? Why do you use the Min(ID)? Thanks!

Comment: Just like pandas, the `drop_duplicates` keeps first (default) and drops matches afterward. First here is the minimum ID. You can easily change to Max(ID).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can do it using [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
with VirtTab as (
    select
      t.*,
      row_number()
        over(partition by column1, column2 order by column1, column2) as rn
    from data t
)
select * from VirtTab
where rn = 1
order by column1, column2;
```

Comment: I'm getting `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.` Any idea why this can be?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you require all records ordered by column1, column2 and column3:

```
Select * from data order by column1,column2,column3
```

Now, on top of this you want to remove duplicate rows in columns participantObjectId and slipObjectId. First partition columns on the basis of participantObjectId and slipObjectId. The query below wraps on top of the above query and adds another field ***id*** which provides unique values for each row of the data.

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY participantObjectId,slipObjectId order by column1,column2,column3) as id
from (select * from data order by column1,column2,column3)
```

On top of this we add another select statement with an added condition to choose only those rows with ***id*** equal to 1.

```
select * from
(select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY participantObjectId,slipObjectId order by column1,column2,column3) as id from 
(Select * from data order by column1,column2,column3
)) where id=1;
```